# Is this algebra a non-commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have an algebraic structure obeying these rules:

- non-commutative multiplication:
  $ A*B \neq B*A $.
- commutative addition:
     $ A+B = B+A $.
- associative addition and multiplication:
     $$ (A+B)+C = A+(B+C) \quad \mbox{ and }\quad  (A*B)*C = A*(B*C) .$$
- distribution on the right:
    $ (A+B)*C = A*C+B*C $.

The elements need not be numbers (I'm using this structure in my A.I. research).

Is it OK if I call it a non-commutative ring?
Or how should I call such a structure?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I think $0$ and $1$ can be added to it, though I don't see their significance in my application yet.  Also I realize that in my structure + is idempotent:  $ A+A = A $.

Adding left distribution does not seem to affect my application, so I guess I can call it a semi-ring.  Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You need a group structure for the addition.

Comment: $A,B$ are matrices?

Comment: @PrasadG: If they were matrices, YKY would have told us that it was left-distributive as well as right-distributive, so presumably not.

Comment: Are there additive or multiplicative identities?  If there are, then you *almost* have a semiring.  In any case, you should not call it a ring unless it is one.  **Edit**: Apparently there's something called a "near-ring"; this is closer to that than a semiring.  Perhaps you should check if it might be a near-ring.  Or maybe just a near-semiring, since that's apparently a known term as well.  That would require very little extra.

Comment: To answer your first question: do not call it a ring.

Comment: @Prasad: Not necessarily matrices, but that is one potential interpretation that can provide powerful techniques.  I'm actually representing natural language sentences using this structure and the elements are words or "concepts".

Answer (score 1):

If the additive structure is a group, i.e. additive inverses exist, then you have a [near-ring.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring) If not, but you have *both* distributive laws, and addition is commutative, then you have a [semiring.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) If neither, then it's generalization of one of these structures (possibly without a standard name).

Comment: Well, there's near-semiring, though that would still require an additive identity and 0a=0: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-semiring

Comment: @Harry Iiirc, there used to be other name(s) for that, which is why I said possibly without a standard name. In any case, the point was to give the OP the terminology need to do searches (your comment did not exist when I started writing the answer).